# Please show me a more elegant way to do this

Tags: javascript

To me, this is the obvious way to do this: given a start point and an end point, tell me if the end point is up / down / left / upleft / downright... etc of the start point. Heres the core of my logic :

```
function getSector() {
    var y = startY - endY;
    var x = startX - endX;
    var angle = Math.atan2(y,x) * 57.29578;//~57 deg per radian
    //atan2(y,x) returns a num between -PI and PI, represents angle in radians
    console.log("angle:" + angle);
    if( (angle > -22.5) && (angle < 22.5) ) attackDir = "left";
    if( (angle > 22.5) && (angle < 67.5) ) attackDir = "upleft";
    if( (angle > 67.5) && (angle < 112.5) ) attackDir = "up";
    if( (angle > 112.5) && (angle < 157.5) ) attackDir = "upright";
    if( (angle > 157.5) && (angle <= 180) ) attackDir = "right";
    if( (angle > -179) && (angle <= -157) ) attackDir = "right";
    if( (angle > -157) && (angle < -112.5) ) attackDir = "downright";
    if( (angle > -112.5) && (angle < -67.5) ) attackDir = "down";
    if( (angle > -67.5) && (angle < -22.5) ) attackDir = "downleft";
    console.log("attackDir:" + attackDir);
}
```

I'm interested in seeing a better way, but more so, HOW you arrived at that way.

I guess a key of sorts would be in order :
left = 0 
up = 90 
right = 179 OR -179 (down is like a negative mirror of up)
down = -90

Comment: Your code only sometimes matches on equality. You should either turn all the `>`'s into `>=` or all the `<`'s into `<=`'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing bounds checking, it's much more readable if you create a function named Between(min, val, max);

```
function Between(min, val, max)
{
 return (val > min) && (val < max);
}
```

In addition, you can test for right/left, and then after that test for down/up..  while appending to a string.  Then your logic is cut down to 4 if statements.

```
var final="";
if(/*IsUp*/) final="up"
else if(/*IsDown*/) final="down"

if(/*IsRight*/) final+= "right";
else if(/*IsLeft*/) final += "left";
```

Edit: As stated by Stefan, 57.29578 is a magical number.  I didn't even realize you meant 180/(Math.Pi)...  As he also stated, the "optimization" you're making makes your code just illegible, and the performance gain is moot.

You should always check for u/d/l/r by x/y position relative to an origin, not by angles.

Comment: damn, that is damn nice. It returns true if both conditions are met. Why cant I come up with that kind of code? =) I spent the better part of 2 hours playing with my example, and you answer within 10 mins. 

Thank you.

Comment: I dont know who / why the downvotes. Should be a way to tell. The above is a good answer, gonna mark it as the answer. TY all!

Comment: There is an argument that you might not consider a direction to be up+left if it was almost entirely up and only slightly left. A common option for that is a "dead zone". Another is to say that if your up is at least k times your left, you count it as pure up. You can of course calculate k (at compile time) to give the same effect as the original angle-based calculation. Handling the quadrants/signs is a minor hassle for this.

Comment: My k factor stuff is pretty close to Muad'dibs answer - it's the slope value for one possible case. Having 4 different slope values (and a sign check to double the cases) is roughly equivalent to having a single k value and doing symmetry over the quadrants/signs for the 8 cases, each case being a dividing line between two result directions.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, BUT this answer isn't that good IMHO. 1. can you elaborate on to form of IsUp / IsDown / IsLeft / IsRight in the answer, they are quite crucial and easily be misinterpreted. 2. I don't find Between(q,w,e) clearer. Not only is it in general not clear which arguments specify the range (e.g. q < w < e versus w < q < e) but especially it DOESN'T SPECIFY if q == w and q == e will return True too! The shown implementation wouldn't work in the questioner's code for the corner cases `val == min` or `val == max` exactly. But exact same bug is easy to spot in the original code.

Comment: Why is `Between` capitalized? That's quite funky, as capitalized functions tend to be constructors.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [slope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope)?

m = dy/dx

Comment: How do you differentiate between 45 degrees and 225 degrees with slope?  The slopes of the lines are exactly the same.

Comment: @ItzWarty - yes, but one is negative.

Comment: @Anurag, no, one is not negative.  The slope between the origin and 1,1 is exactly the same as the slope from the origin to -1,-1.  The line is exactly the same.  As such, topright will have the same slope as bottomleft...

Comment: @ItzWarty - you're right, slope will only give the general direction of the line, but need an additional step to disambiguate.

Comment: yeah, I realized after I posted this that there would be no way to differentiate all the directions this way.  I deserve the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function just functions by binning the angle range [-PI, PI] in 8 equal bins, there is a simple linear mapping from the angle to a bin index. This is a general pattern for adding labels over a fixed number of equally sized bins over a fixed range.

Example:

```
var angle = Math.atan2(y,x) * 57.29578;//~57 deg per radian
```

where angle lies within range [-180, 180]. So, `(angle + 157.5) / 45.0` is within [-0.5, 7.5] range, and `(angle+157.5)/45.0 + 0.5` within [0.0, 8.0] range.
This bins are seperated at 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 ... 7.5, so rounding the value will bring everythin at the left/right of the boundry to a correct bin index:

```
var bin_index = parseInt(Math.round((angle + 157.5) / 45.0 + 0.5));
```

Since bin 8 and bin 0 are actually the same, we use the module operator to merge these bin indices next:

```
bin_index = bin_index % 8; // bin_index == 8 becomes bin_index == 0 too
```

Now you can look up your result string using the bin index :)

```
var bin_labels = ['right', 'downright', 'down', 'downleft', 'left', 'upleft', 'up', 'upright'];
return bin_labels[bin_index];
```

*EDIT*: putting above lines together:

```
function getSector() {
    var dy = startY - endY;
    var dx = startX - endX;
    var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx) * 180.0 / Math.PI; // we can assume -180.0 <= angle <= 180.0

    // partition angle space in 8 equal bins,
    // lowest bin should have index 0, the highest 7
    var bin_index = parseInt(Math.round((angle + 157.5) / 45.0 + 0.5));
    bin_index = bin_index % 8; // ensure bin_index == 8 -> bin_index == 0

    // return the correct bin label
    var bin_labels = ['right', 'downright', 'down', 'downleft', 'left', 'upleft', 'up', 'upright'];
    return bin_labels[bin_index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use angles. Also, if you're using 180/PI, just write 180/PI. You get very little speed for a huge readability impact.

```
var dy = endY - startY;
var dx = endX - startX;
var isUp = dy < 0;
var isDown = dy > 0;//probably use some fudge here for a better neutral zone, if you're parsing input
var isLeft = dx < 0;
var isRight = dx > 0;
```

This assumes a coordinate system that has (0,0) in the top left, and (n,n) in the bottom right, as in many graphics applications.

Comment: ahh i see what you did there... clever.

could go even further :


var direction = endY < startY ? "top" : "bottom";
direction += endX < startX ? "left" : "right";


and that would make everything turn out to a topleft / topright / bottomleft / bottomright.. which if you think of it, most gestures arent perfectly vertical or horizontal.

Comment: If you need gestures, you'll want to change "0" to some "fudge" number.

Answer (score 0):

You might have less code by indexing a suitable array of strings ("right","downright","downright", ...) with `parseInt((angle+180)/22.5)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if      (angle <= -157)  attackDir = "right";
else if (angle < -112.5) attackDir = "downright";
else if (angle < -67.5)  attackDir = "down";
else if (angle < -22.5)  attackDir = "downleft";
else if (angle < 22.5)   attackDir = "left";
else if (angle < 67.5)   attackDir = "upleft";
else if (angle < 112.5)  attackDir = "up";
else if (angle < 157.5)  attackDir = "upright";
else if (angle <= 180)   attackDir = "right";
```